# How can I see the full charge capacity of my battery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery

I have a Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.2.

Is there any way for me to see the full charge capacity of the phone's battery, so that I can compare it to the spec?

What I have in mind is something like what Lenovo's Power Manager tells me about my laptop's battery:

[image]

Is there anything like this for Android?

Answer (score 3):

Without special measuring equipment and some kind of a reference - no you can't (not in mAh). There is no app that would provide you with that kind of information, at least not accurate enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app in the market that claims to do this for HTC phones (search "battery mAh" to find it) so I believe its theoretically possible.  I'd guess that instead of actually measuring the enery stored, its making estimates based on the phones specs and actual use.  I don't know how accurate it is and I'm pretty sure it would not be accurate on your phone.  One problem is that even an estimated battery capacity in mAh is very hardware dependent so you'd need an app specifically for your device and there isn't one at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Open the case and look at the battery.  It should say 1500 mAh.

Comment: That would be the spec. I'm asking about the actual current full charge capacity.  It deteriorates over time.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to check how much energy is stored in a battery, that's why the charge is measured in percent.  You could approximate it by hooking the battery up to something with a constant current draw and timing how long it took to drain, but the phone can't do that.  You can gain an even rougher approximation by comparing your current average battery life on one charge to that of when you first got it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [3C Battery Monitor Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw) to measure what is my *real* capacity. It monitors the state of charge of the battery (charging and discharging).

I can check that the original capacity was 2100 mAh, and the current capacity it's about 1400 mAh, two thirds of the specification.

[image: historic charges]